# Sammy.js External Navigation

Tags: sharepoint, knockout.js, sammy.js

I have built a SharePoint 2010 web part that is a single page app using knockout and Sammy to navigate between views of the SPA. Everything works fine within the SPA web part, but if I try to navigate to another page in SharePoint, the Sammy.js routing kicks in and just reloads my SPA home view. Is there a way to "override" the Sammy.js navigation when clicking a link outside the SPA web part?

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely. Instead I would remove Sammy and make the navigation work using templates in knockout dependent on the current view.

Optionally wire it into Sammy so it could run stand-alone with proper URL routing, or simply nested inside the dom somewhere not using Sammy.